# How delete/remove "created by" and "last modified" in form sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]

I need to remove or delete the information(`encircled in above image`) on the list form of SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 3):

If it´s only this list you want to remove it from you can use css.

1. Go to the list, choose "list" (close to files and browse)
2. Choose "form web parts" and "deafult display form".
3. In the editor click "add a webpart" and find "script editor".
4. In script editor you can link to an css file (put the css file in style library and link in the script editor) or just put in the css code (remember the  tags).

Css example:

`.ms-formtoolbar{
    display:none;
}`

The class `.ms-formtoolbar` contains both the created by and last modified part.

You can as well alter the master page, but it might have some unforeseen consequences consequences that can impact other parts of SharePoint.

Edit:
By using css you don´t delete the data, it is  just not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit view page in SharePoint Designer and remove created and modified from the form.

Also you can use the CSS to hide details all over the site as suggested by Andreas otherwise can use Designer to remove the field.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use the class .ms-toolbar or .ms-formtoolbar it will also hide the Button and small tool bar from the Display and EditForm.

you can use the inner class .ms-descriptiontext that is only for your round circle contents, just copy the below three line and add on your List Form to hide

.ms-descriptiontext { display:none; }

Comment: <style>

.ms-descriptiontext { display:none; }

</style>